# How I can Install Turtlebot on ROS Lunar?

Tags: ros, turtlebot, ros-lunar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Only turtle bot is available for Indigo version of ROS. How I can get Turtlebot installed for ROS Lunar?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282114/how-i-can-install-turtlebot-on-ros-lunar?/) by [Deep Seth](https://answers.ros.org/users/33611/deep-seth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-02-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The TurtleBot team has chosen to focus on the Long Term Support releases only. You can install it from either supported LTS distro, Indigo or Kinetic, at the moment.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0